# Java Beginner --Type of words in the code

Tags: java, android

```
public void sendMessage (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.edit_message);
}
```

I am confused with the different of "Intent intent" type? Is it a classifier or variable or class? Why is the first letter of "Intent" is capitalize and the next one is not? also what is the type of "(Edit Text)", "findViewById" and (R.id.edit_message) ?

The code is copied from developer android website.

Thank you

Comment: You need to learn some Java basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you're using c#, so my guess is that you're working with the Xamarin Framework? Either way, it'd be a good thing to post with your question.

The Intent *class* is a class that represents something that is going to be done by the Android OS. Instead of quoting documentation, I will link you to it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/intent/) (This is on the Xamarin website, though the Intent type is the same stuff). In order to fully grasp it I recommend you looking around to see an example, of which there are many.

The reason why Intent is written capitalized because it represents a type, which is syntax. the 'intent' written after Intent is a variable containing an instance of Intent (an Intent object if you will).

EditText (that space is most likely a typo) is also a type like Intent, however instead of it being used here as a way to declare an instance of itself, here it is used to *cast* whatever follows next to its type. Casting is a way of forcing (if it is in fact possible) an object (or instance) to convert to the type you're casting to.

For instance you could cast an instance of the type 'Int' to a 'Double' like so:

```
Int my_integer = 5;
double my_double = (Double)my_integer;
```

findByViewId pretty much speaks for itself, it finds some view (which is some element that is on your screen) by the *id* you pass as a parameter. 
Apparently it returns a type that is convertable to the EditText type, because if it were not, the casting would result in a compile error.

Oh and yea, if you want to start becoming an Android developer, learn a language in which you can develope an Android app, as all of these questions are pretty much unrelated to App Development, but rather to programming in object oriented languages.

Answer (score 0):

Intent is a class defined in android's framework,intent is a variable and its type is Intent,like String s,String is type and s is varaiable name.You can change intent to any legal name .
And not Edit Text,is EditText .